# Merging Two Rows Into One Longer Row (Pandas)

Tags: pandas

I have a data set with 1048 rows, each being two sides of the same data set (a Democrat and Republican campaign in the same race).

`year label can_par_aff  can_inc_cha_ope_sea  dem_per  gop_per   ind_con
0  2014  AK-1         DEM                    1     40.8     51.6  36500.64

1  2014  AK-1         REP                    0     40.8     51.6  43369.00`

And I need to merge them into a single row with ind_con_dem and ind_con_gop (so I can create comparison metrics).

I cannot seem to find a simple way to automate this.  The important factors are that it groups by both 'year' AND 'label' and that it creates new column names.

I can do this with very specific code, but I cannot figure out a way to generalize it.

Thoughts, ideas, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is `df` and that `label` and `year` uniquely identify records, try:

```
df_dem = df[df['can_par_aff'] == 'DEM'].groupby(['year','label']).last()
df_rep = df[df['can_par_aff'] == 'REP'].groupby(['year','label']).last()

joined = df_dem.join(df_rep, lsuffix = '_dem', rsuffix = '_gop')
```

It's grouped by `year` and `label` and creates new names as specified above.

Answer (score 1):

This also indexes our your DataFrame (`df`) based on year and label.

```
df = df.set_index(['year', 'label', 'can_par_aff']).unstack()
>>> df

             can_inc_cha_ope_sea       dem_per        gop_per         ind_con       
can_par_aff                  DEM  REP      DEM   REP      DEM   REP       DEM    REP
year label                                                                          
2014 AK-1                      1    0     40.8  40.8     51.6  51.6  36500.64  43369
```